# SQL subtracting a string column from another string column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to subtract two string columns from another string column.

I have acheived this in the past in Oracle using  the below

```
SELECT
C.MANUFACTURER,
C.MODEL_GROUP,
REGEXP_REPLACE(C.VARIANT, '^'||C.MANUFACTURER || ' +' || C.MODEL_GROUP) "VAR DESC",
C.VARIANT
FROM STD_BI.RL2_CONTRACTS_VW C
```

I now need to acheive the same in MS SQL any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for REGEXP support in MSSQL or how to do simple string REPLACE?

Comment: Appreciate any sample data

Comment: Some sample data would also be appreciated.  Also note that SQL Server has no built in support for regex replacement.

Comment: Looks like you mean _concat_, not _subtract_. Try `+` instead of `||`.

Comment: @jarlh No...look closely...he is concatenating together a regex pattern.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, but does SQL Server support the `||` concatenation nowadays?

Comment: Well the OP actually posted an Oracle query.  No, SQL Server doesn't support `||` or regex replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Subtract" is surely a misnomer here.  The OP appears to want to remove a string at the beginning of another string.

From this point on, I am assuming that `MANUFACTURER` and `MODEL_GROUP` do not contain any regular expression wildcard characters.

There is a challenge with multiple spaces.  If there are not too many, then you can do.  For instance, this handles one or two spaces:

```
SELECT C.MANUFACTURER, C.MODEL_GROUP,
       (CASE WHEN C.VARIANT LIKE C.MANUFACTURER + ' ' + C.MODEL_GROUP + '%'
             THEN STUFF(C.VARIANT, 1, LEN(C.MANUFACTURER + ' ' + C.MODEL_GROUP), '')
             WHEN C.VARIANT LIKE C.MANUFACTURER + '  ' + C.MODEL_GROUP + '%' AND
             THEN STUFF(C.VARIANT, 1, LEN(C.MANUFACTURER + '  ' + C.MODEL_GROUP), '')
             ELSE C.VARIANT
        END) as [VAR DESC],
       C.VARIANT
FROM STD_BI.RL2_CONTRACTS_VW C;
```

EDIT:

Here is a more complete solution:

```
SELECT C.MANUFACTURER, C.MODEL_GROUP,
       (CASE WHEN C.VARIANT LIKE C.MANUFACTURER + ' %' + C.MODEL_GROUP + '%' AND
                  C.VARIANT NOT LIKE C.MANUFACTURER + ' %[^ ]%' + C.MODEL_GROUP + '%'

             THEN STUFF(LTRIM(STUFF(C.VARIANT, 1, LEN(C.MANUFACTURER), '')), 1, LEN(C.MODEL_GROUP), '')
             ELSE C.VARIANT
        END) as [VAR DESC],
       C.VARIANT
FROM STD_BI.RL2_CONTRACTS_VW C;
```

This tests for just spaces between the two strings (the `not like` is checking for something other than a space).  The replacement is then in three steps -- remove the manufacturer, then the spaces, then the model group.

Comment: Hi Many thanks for your input, however, this solution is returning the full varient string in all cases.

Comment: Hi Please see below sample data                                                                                        VARIANT
AUDI A3 DIESEL SPORTBACK 2.0 TDI SE Technik 5dr Manual 150

MANUFACTURER 
AUDI

MODEL_GROUP
A3   

I am looking to retreive this 
DIESEL SPORTBACK 2.0 TDI SE Technik 5dr Manual 150

Comment: How does it work for subtracting two [string columns within a single dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69540138/10452700) in PySpark?

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some time on this one as much for my own satisfaction and in addition to the answer above, I have come up with the following which also generates the correct answer.

```
SUBSTRING(FV.VARIANT, LEN(FV.MANUFACTURER + ' ' + FV.MODEL_RANGE + ' ') + 1 , LEN(FV.VARIANT))
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was kinda easier to solve, I just needed to remove "xxxx" (the first 4 characters) at the start of a column from some rows:

> UPDATE coluna  SET columToEdit = SUBSTRING(columToEdit, 5, 200);

Comment: question is for subtract not substring