# What is the best PySpark practice to subtract two string columns within a single spark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, replace, substring

Let's say I have a spark dataframe as below:

| data | A | Expected_column= data - A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://example1.org/path/to/file?param=42#fragment | param=42#fragment | https://example1.org/path/to/file? |
| https://example2.org/path/to/file | NaN | https://example2.org/path/to/file |

I was thinking if there is a suitable filtering mechanism by subtracting two **string** columns from each other like:

```
sdf1 = sdf.withColumn('Expected_column', ( sdf['data'] - sdf['A'] ))
```

This returns `Null` for all rows of column `Expected_column`. I checked different solutions like this [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64691881/10452700), but they are dealing with two dataframe while my case is within a single data frame as well as their issues are not dealing with string columns. The closest question was about [date differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67967876/10452700), which are again not my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the function you're looking for is called [`replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.8/api/sql/index.html#replace):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sdf.withColumn("data - A", F.expr("replace(data, coalesce(A, ''), '')")).show(
    truncate=False
)
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
|data                                               |A                |data - A                          |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
|https://example1.org/path/to/file?param=42#fragment|param=42#fragment|https://example1.org/path/to/file?|
|https://example2.org/path/to/file                  |null             |https://example2.org/path/to/file |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: changed `regexp_replace` with simple `replace`. it should work

Comment: it works perfectly for all cases now. So what was the reason of difference of replacement performance between `replace` & `regexp_replace` ?